# Inequalities with nested for Loops

Tags: excel, vba

it's me again.

I have a nested for loop, looking at each cell within a range then moving onto the next column (needs to be nested, even for 2 as later on i have 300 columns and rows to check (this is a test attempt)) The macro checks the value of the cell then changes the color of the cell dependent on the value. However when i run the code, the macro colors everything with Color Index 36 irreverent of the value of the cell. Can anyone explain why?

```
Dim i12 as long 
Dim i9 as long 

i12 = 3
For i12 = i12 To 4
i12 = i12
i9 = 21
    For i9 = i9 To 71
        i9 = i9
        If 0 < Cells(i9, i12) < 1 Then
            Cells(i9, i12).Select
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        ElseIf Cells(i9, i12) < 0 Then
            Cells(i9, i12).Select
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
        End If
    Next i9
Next i12
```

I'm thinking that the issue is from the `0 < Cells(i9, i12) < 1` here, maybe because VBA isn't able to cope with this equation, but i'm not sure. 
Thanks for any help you are able to provide .

Comment: You are right in your thought that 0 < Cells(i9, i12) < 1 is wrong. if I added brackets, to show the precedence, it would read (0 < Cells(i9, i12)) < 1 so you are comparing the true or false value of 0 < Cells(i9, i12) to 1.
Separate it into two clause with an "And" operator between them.

Comment: When `0 < Cells(i9, i12)` evaluates to `False` (i.e. `0`), `0 < 1` evaluates to `True`. When `0 < Cells(i9, i12)` evaluates to `True` (i.e. `-1`), `-1 < 1` also evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts thank you very much for your comment, nice to have a explication as to why something isn't working rather than just the solution, i find that this always helps  me in the future with issues relating to this.

Comment: FWIW you should do `Cells(i9, i12).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` instead of `Select`ing and working off `Selection` like macro-recorder code. Also note that `Cells` unqualified with a `Workbook` object is implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet` and this is going to create issues one day or another, *especially* if you `Select` things. Do e.g. `Sheet1.Cells(i9, i12)` instead of just `Cells`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you cannot do this, `If 0 < Cells(i9, i12) < 1 Then`.

You need two conditions,

```
If Cells(i9, i12) > 0 And Cells(i9, i12) < 1 Then
```

---

You also do not need to select the cell(s):

Replace

```
Cells(i9, i12).Select
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

with

```
Cells(i9, i12).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

(When you see `Select` followed by `.Selection` you can remove both terms.)

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly :)

Comment: If it worked perfectly, you should accept the answer as correct, not just comment.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts i cant, not for another 10 mins or so for some reason

Comment: @AndyG. Thank you for that tip, didnt know that either. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like AndyG said, you need to define the condition twice in the IF statement, and use Interior.ColorIndex to set the color.